# Tracks vs signal planes for high power LED PCB

Tags: led, pcb

I am designing a PCB for high power LEDs using [Luminus SST-10-UV-A130-F365-00](https://download.luminus.com/datasheets/Luminus_SST-10-UV_Datasheet.pdf). I have been looking at some commercial modules and have seen that many of them use signal planes instead of tracks for current transmission. Is this recommended instead of using tracks? In the case where the LEDs have an additional thermal pad in addition to the anode and cathode, will it also be advisable to use signal planes for current transmission, or just use the flat for the thermal pad?

Example of signal plane based PCB attached.

[image]

Comment: What type LEDs are you using?

Comment: Do you mean “signal plane” or “single plane”?

Comment: The large areas of copper are for thermal distribution, not current

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm using UVA LEDs. Refrence: SST-10-UV-A130-F365-00

Comment: @RussellH signal planes, the planes that transmit the current and dissipate the heat

Comment: @Neil_UK you're right: But they also transmit current, don´t they?

Comment: They don't need to be that big for the current, narrow tracks are all that's needed. But for heat, the bigger the better, in that application.

Comment: @Neil_UK I see your point, thanks!

Comment: A number of LED vendors provide detailed technical papers reviewing the thermal requirements and best practices board layout for their products. If you're unsure I recommend looking through one of these papers.

Comment: Please accept Tim's answer (put a green check mark next to his answer) if his answer is acceptable to you. In that way you reward him for work done (with points),.and signal to others that the answer worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the datasheet, we see the mounting base has metal pads:

[image: Luminus SST-10-UV-A130-F365-00 mechanical drawing]

This type of package is made on a metallized ceramic substrate, probably Al<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub> (or possibly AlN) for good thermal conductivity.

Such a package sinks heat mostly through the middle pad -- directly underneath the chip itself, the shortest thermal path -- but all pads have some contribution.

The easiest way to harness this thermal resistance is to use wide connections to each pad, and thermal vias to the middle pad if possible.

Most likely, the pictured design is doing exactly the same thing.  They may indeed be using a comparable package.

The headline claims 1.4 °C/W thermal resistance, but does not state to what reference plane that's measured.  I would guess the overall package/case, so, not including a typical PCB mounting situation, which will count extra, and depends on layout and type (of course with metal-core PCB performing the best).

There is no signal motivation here; frequencies are most likely low (DC, maybe some switching ripple, or rectified mains), and the wide pour areas act as patch antennas so would be contraindicated for anything with significant high-frequency content.

There's almost no reason to use thin traces between LEDs; I'm having trouble thinking up a scenario myself.  Mind, just because I can't think of one, doesn't mean it doesn't exist -- engineering is a far too diverse topic to make such a claim, and not also have justification behind it.  That is, there's a use for almost anything you can think up, given an odd enough use-case.  But they will be odd -- rare, unusual.  Whereas the motivation behind usual applications, like LED lighting, are mainly thermal: spread the heat out from the near-point source, to keep its internal temperature as low as possible given the available materials and ambient conditions.